# Wordpress Crayon Plugin dirty my code

Tags: wordpress, codehighlighter

I am using a plugin named `Crayon` to format my code in wordpress, however after I have changed config settings, I found the code in my post was dirtied!

It shows like this following:
[Code Dirtied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMwq.png)

[image]

What can I do to repair it or what wrong config setting have I made?

I've tried to reset the config and it doesn't work.

- Crypon Version: _2.7.2_beta - 25th April, 2015
- Wordpress Version:WordPress 4.5.3

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Stop using the plugin, because the square brackets in the shortcode are being interferred with by the square brackets in the output used within the shortcode.

Is there a reason why you can't style it using `<pre>` and CSS?

Comment: i using a markdown editor to write my post and publish it to wordpress by xmlrpc, so i do not want to edit it anymore in wordpress. so i want to find a plugin to beauty the code.  Any suggestion for my requiment?